# How to add strings to a 2d array of char elements?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char

I have the below program written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int age[5];
    char name[5][10];

    age[0]=10;
    age[1]=20;
    age[2]=30;
    age[3]=25;
    age[4]=40;

    name[0]="abc";
    name[1]="abc";
    name[2]="abc";
    name[3]="abc";
    name[4]="abc";

    cout<<name[0]<<" is "<<age[0]<<"years old";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<name[1]<<" is "<<age[1]<<"years old";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<name[2]<<" is "<<age[2]<<"years old";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<name[3]<<" is "<<age[3]<<"years old";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<name[4]<<" is "<<age[4]<<"years old";
    cout<<"\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

When I compile and run it, I get these errors:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert
>   from 'const char [3]' to 'char [10]'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert
>   from 'const char [2]' to 'char [10]'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert
>   from 'const char [2]' to 'char [10]'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert
>   from 'const char [2]' to 'char [10]'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert
>   from 'const char [2]' to 'char [10]'
>           There is no context in which this conversion is possible

I am running MSVC 2008 under Windows 7. I have tried many possible solutions but I failed in fixing this. Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating the `name` array as if it was defined thus:

```
char *name[5];
```

So either define it that way, or use the following code to populate it:

```
strcpy(name[0], "abc");
strcpy(name[1], "abc");
strcpy(name[2], "abc");
strcpy(name[3], "abc");
strcpy(name[4], "abc");
```

I prefer the former choice.  The point being you are trying to assign a `char *` to a `char []` which is what `strcpy` is for.  Given you are manipulating initialized C strings in this case anyway, you might as well deal with `char *` throughout the code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::string` for this purpose. The use of `char*` and `char[]` to represent strings is deprecated in C++ for many good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Given the program snippet, `name` can be initialized at the declaration itself.

```
char name[5][10] = { "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc" } ;
       // ^ index 5 is not necessary. char name[][10] = { .. } would also suffice.
```

Specified the length of each row is **10** but only using first **3** indexes of it. Every **3rd** index ( i.e., 4th element in the array ) is automatically added with a `'\0'`.

Initialization can be done in case of `age` array too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `std::string name[10]` instead of 2d char's array. In this case only you can assign new values to the strings through operator '='.
Otherwise you should to use array of `char*` and use `strcpy()` function for assignment.